Compare less for two __m256i variables (total ordering)
for many algorithms we need a less than operator. How can i get that operation with a __m256i variable? I only care about total ordering and not if it's "correct" in a mathematical sense like "1 < 2"
I found a solution for _m128i:
Compare two __m128i values for total order
And I also found one for AVX-512 family, but what would be the equivalant with _m256i AVX family?

And the linked solution does not work for __m256i (after replacing _mm_... by _mm256_...)?

There is no _mm256_cmplt...

Are you searching a solution for AVX1 (i.e., without AVX2?) Otherwise, _mm_cmplt_epiX(a,b) is just an alias for _mm_cmpgt_epiX(b,a) (and availability may depend on what compiler you use).

Well, the Solution must be 
const int mask_lt = _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_cmpgt_epi8(b, a));
const int mask_gt = _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_cmpgt_epi8(a, b));
return mask_gt < mask_lt;

then. Correct?

Yes, that should work (feel free to write this as answer). Btw you can format code by enclosing it with backtick ` characters.

Derived from the comments:
const int mask_lt = _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_cmpgt_epi8(b, a));
const int mask_gt = _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_cmpgt_epi8(a, b));
return mask_gt < mask_lt;

